# Simple PHP MySQL Query Grouping Task

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a quiz using PHP and jQuery, with the questions and answers stored in a database table. Below is an example of the values stored in my database table:

```
Question | Answer | Correct
What color is an apple? | red | 1
What color is an apple? | yellow | 2
What color is an apple? | blue | 2
```

And here's my query...

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Q.URL, Q.Question, Q.Answer, Q.Correct
 FROM 1_quiz Q");
$stm->execute(array(
 'MyURL'=>$MyURL
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $URL = $row['URL'];
 $Question = $row['Question'];
 $Answer = $row['Answer'];
 $Correct = $row['Correct'];

$Q1[] = '<div id="'.$URL.'" style="">'.$Question.'
<div><input type="radio" name="'.$Question.'" id="" value="" />
<label for="">'.$Answer.'</label></div>
</div>';
}

echo join ($Q1, '');
```

As expected, it displays this:

```
What color are apples?
red
What color are apples?
yellow
What color are apples?
blue
Where is Paris?
Russia
Where is Paris?
Alaska
Where is Paris?
France
```

How can I modify the code so it displays like this, displaying each question just once?:

```
What color are apples?
red
yellow
blue
```

I tried GROUP BY Q.Question and GROUP BY Q.Answer, but those didn't work.

The obvious answer is to store the questions in a separate database table, and I may be forced to do that eventually. However, I'd like to try to keep everything in one spreadsheet/database table, as it makes it much easier to manage.

Comment: I think trying to keep everything in one table makes things harder, not easier (especially when it comes to writing queries to do things, as you are now discovering). Move your answers to a new table, and put a foreign key between the two. The great thing there is you have less unnecessary redundancy and you can enforce the relationships between things using constraints.

Comment: Consider normalizing your database, splitting it into questions and answers tables.

Comment: OK, I'll go with two tables. One question: By "foreign key," do you mean a third table, or simply a field of ID's that each table shares in common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving to a new table is best, but you can still achieve what you want here.

You will need two queries, in the first you get the distinct list of questions, something like:

```
$stm2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT distinct Q.URL, Q.Question FROM 1_quiz Q"); 
$stm2->execute(array('MyURL'=>$MyURL));
```

then you will have two loops, the outer loop just loops on the questions. The inner loop uses the same query you have in your question but filters the answers for the current question from the outer loop.